# In Xcode under iPhone-SDK 3.0, where can I set my Bundle Identifier globally

Tags: iphone, xcode

To clarify, I mean that when I create a new project in the *AppName-Info.plist* there is a key named *Bundle Identifier*. It defaults to **com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}**

This means that I have to change "yourcompany" to my company name every time I create a new project that I want to run on a device.

When I first setup Xcode under SDK 2.2, I found a way to set it so my company name got put in new projects automatically, but I've forgotten how I did it.

Poking around Xcode prefs and searching on Google produced no good results.

Where is that setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the template for new applications. By default, it will be found in:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates`

There you will find all the various project templates where you can change the defaults to something more to your liking. It might be better, however, to copy the default templates into your personal Library and then select the template from there when creating new projects. To do this, copy the templates into:

`~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates` and they will show up under the *User Defined Templates* heading in Xcode.

Comment: To complete your answer, in each template type, e.g. "Tab Bar Application", "Utility Application", etc... open the plist called "___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___-Info.plist". Change the Bundle Identifier value there by replacing "yourcompany" with your actual company.

Comment: Looks like you have to change it in all the template files every time a new version of Xcode comes out. Dude, gyp.